# Передача значений из одного класса в другой

Tags: c++, классы

Недавно начал изучать классы в с++, интересует вопрос: как передать значение, полученное в одном классе в другой.

Пробовал через указатели, но ничего не вышло.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int *a;
public:
    void set_a(int set)
    {
        a = &set;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    void show_b()
    {
        b = *(A::a);
        std::cout << b << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj_a;
    B obj_b;

    obj_a.set_a(10);
    obj_b.show_b();

    return 0;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы значение переменной а передалось переменную b.

Comment: есть такие штуки сеттеры и геттеры.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле из вашего примера кода непонятно, что вы стараетесь достичь.:)

Тем не менее, касаясь вашего кода, то параметры функций являются их локальными переменными, которые прекратят свою жизнь после завершения работы функций. Поэтому в этой функции

```
void set_a(int set)
{
    a = &set;
}
```

указатель `a` будет содержать адрес объекта, который уже не будет существовать, что приведет к неопределенному поведению программы.
Вы должны создать копию локальной переменной в динамической памяти и адрес копии присвоить члену класса `a`. При этом следует не забыть освободить память, выделенную динамически.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    int *a = nullptr;
public:
    ~A() { delete a; }

    void set_a(int set)
    {
        if ( a == nullptr ) a = new int;                
        *a = set;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    void show_b()
    {
        b = *(A::a);
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;

    b.set_a( 10 );

    b.show_b();

    return 0;
}
```

Или можно переписать программу следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    int *a = nullptr;
public:
    ~A() { delete a; }

    void set_a(int set)
    {
        if ( a == nullptr ) a = new int;                
        *a = set;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    void show_b()
    {
        b = *(A::a);
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;

    A &ra = b;

    ra.set_a( 10 );

    b.show_b();

    return 0;
}
```

В этом примере объявляется ссылка на объект класса `B`, но имеющая тип `A`. Используя эту ссылку вы можете обращаться только к методам, объявленным в классе `A`.

Что касается вашего вопроса

> как передать значение, полученное в одном классе в другой.

то это делается с помощью методов класса, которые возвращают полученное значение.:)

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    void set_a( int set )
    {
        a = set;
    }

    int get_a() const
    {
        return a;
    }
};

class B
{
private:    
    int b;

public:
    void show_b( const A &a )
    {
        b = a.get_a();
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;

    a.set_a( 10 );

    B b;

    b.show_b( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47710/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow-------).

Answer (score 2):

Следует различать класс(тип) и объект(экземпляр) данного типа. классы позволяют организовать код (разделить его на части). экземпляры класса (объекты) разделяют данные. При этом,глубоко неправильно давать одному классу доступ до внутренних данных другого класса, т.к. в сложном случае, когда, например, требуется выделение/освобождение памяти поде ресурс одного класса, невозможно во другом классе узнать что: 1) память уже инициализирована, 2) память уже освобождена. И это будет приводить к трудно отлавливаемым ошибкам. Правильно - разделять ресурсы и не давать к ним доступ за пределами экземпляра класса.

1) вариант, когда нам нужно иметь один объект, но есть наследование (разносим функционал по разным классам, но пользуемся одним объектом)
1. так неправильно

```
class A
{
protected:
    int *a;
public:
    void set_a(int set)
    {
        a = &set; // так сохраняется адрес временной переменной set созданной для вызова этого метода, после возврата из метода адрес этой переменной не валиден
    }
};
```

должно быть

```
class A
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    void set_a(const int& set)
    {
        a = set; // так мы сохраним значение 
    }
};
```

2.

```
class B : public A
{
protected:
    int b; // просто не нужна, ибо B имеет доступ к полям A (public и protected)
public:
...
```

должно быть так

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void show_b()
    {
        std::cout << a << endl;
    }
};
```

3. в этом примере

   int main() 
   {
       A a; 
       a.set_a( 10 );

   ```
   B b;
   b.show_b( );

   return 0;
   ```

   }

а и b - разные объекты.
так будет работать.

```
int main() 
{
    B b;

    A *pa = &b; 
    B *pb = &b; 
    a->set_a( 10 );

    b.show_b();
    pb->b.show_b();

    return 0;
}
```

---

2) пользуемся двумя классами, двумя объектами разных типов, один из классов имеет доступ к данным второго класса

```
class A
{
    int val;
public:
    int get(void) const { return val; }
    void set(const int& v) { val = v; }
};

class B
{
   int val;
public:
   B(const A& a) 
   {
      val = a.get();
   }

   void show(void)
   {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    A a; a.set(10);
    B b(a);
    b.show();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Исправил, как вы сказали, все равно не работает. При вызове метода show_b() объекта obj_b выводится мусор.

Comment: ага, нашел еще одну ошибку, поправляю ответ